# Call C# .Net DLL in delphi 7

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, com, delphi-7

Anyone know how can I create a C# dll which can be called in Delphi 7 program?
I do that through the ComVisibleAttribute but delphi program takes error.

C# DLL Code (Class Library Project):

```
namespace MyTest
{
        [ComVisible(true)]
        [GuidAttribute("EF00685F-1C14-4D05-9EFA-538B3137D86C")]
        [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
        public class MainTest
        {
                public int AddP(int value)
                {
                   return value + 314;
                } 
        }
}
```

Delphi 7 Main Program Code:

```
function AddP(Value: integer): integer; stdcall;
  external 'DelphiTest.dll';

procedure TfrmMain.btnConvertClick(Sender: TObject);
var value : double;
Begin
      Text := IntToStr(AddP(10000));
End;
```

It takes error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK
>   to close the application.

Comment: does this help: http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/master-delphi-7/content/LiB0128.html

Comment: That's a managed DLL. You can't call LoadLibrary on it. You need a COM server, or a mixed mode DLL. The latter is most easily done with C++-CLI. Or with Robert Giesecke's IL hacks, UnmanagedExports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is not regarding Delphi, but about the general things. No exact solution, only links. Basically, you have several options to call managed code from unmanaged:

**Create COM object.** You create c# dll and class with COM-related attributes `MainTest`. Then you register your dll in the system (using regasm.exe). As a result your Com-object can be consumed from any language including Delphi. Check [this post](https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/creating-a-com-server-using-c/) out for more info

**Make a wrapper with Managed c++ (c++/cli)** This is also a very popular technique. The thing is that c++/cli dlls can mix managed and unmanaged code. So you basically create unmanaged wrappers for managed code. Check [this post](http://pragmateek.com/using-c-from-native-c-with-the-help-of-ccli-v2/) out for more info

**Use IL hack**. This facility would work for static methods only and it's more like a hack since you need to change IL code. [This post](http://www.blong.com/Articles/DotNetInteropD8/Interop1/Win32AndDotNetInterop.htm#InversePInvoke) describes it

So you're basically trying to mix 1st and 3rd approaches. You need to stick to one. Personally I prefer second approach since it is easy to deploy and safe to use

Comment: The IL hacks have been automates by Robert Giesecke's UnmanagedExports, fwiw